# Is there a workaround for using .scenePhase with SignInWithAppleButton in a NavigationStack causing a nav stack pop and login to fail?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I converted my app to use the new NavigationStack in my onboarding flow. My login view that uses SignInWithAppleButton failed. What seemed to happen is my view containing the button popped away when Apple's sign-in button was shown. This meant my handlers were gone, so none of my handlers were called. The same code outside the NavigationStack works fine.

I eventually tracked this down to a very unexpected statement.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestNavSignInApp: App {
    // When scenePhase isn't commented out the SignInWithAppleButton view pops off
    // and the sign-in never occurs. Comment it out, and everything works fine.
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var onboarding = OnboardingFlow()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack(path: $onboarding.path) {
            Button("Start") {
                onboarding.start()
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: OnboardDestination.self) { destination in
                ViewFactory.viewForDestination(destination)
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(onboarding)
    }
}

enum OnboardDestination {
    case welcomPage
    case loginPage
}

class ViewFactory {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    static func viewForDestination(_ destination: OnboardDestination) -> some View {
         
        switch destination {
        case .welcomPage:
            WelcomeView()
        case .loginPage:
            SignInWithAppleView()
        }
    }
}

class OnboardingFlow: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    
    func gotoHomePage() {
        path.removeLast(path.count)
    }
    
    func gotoPrev() {
        path.removeLast()
    }
    
    func start() {
        path.append(OnboardDestination.welcomPage)
    }
    
    func next() {
        path.append(OnboardDestination.loginPage)
    }
}

struct WelcomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var onboarding: OnboardingFlow
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Next") {
            onboarding.next()
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

struct SignInWithAppleView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var onboarding: OnboardingFlow
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 18) {
            
            SignInWithAppleButton(
                .signIn,
                onRequest: configure,
                onCompletion: handle
            )
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
    
    func configure(_ request: ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest) {
        request.requestedScopes = [.email, .fullName]
    }
    
    func handle(_ authResult: Result<ASAuthorization, Error>) {
        print("Handle:")
        
        switch authResult {
        
        case.success(let auth):
           print("Authorization successful: \(auth)")
            
            switch auth.credential {
            
            case let credential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
                print("credential: \(credential)")
                
            default:
                print("Authorization default credential: \(auth.credential.description)")
            }
            
        case.failure(let error):
            print("Authorization failed:error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this would happen. While scenePhase isn't a must have, I was wondering if anyone could explain what is happening and a possible workaround?

Comment: The really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have a project but I don't see a way to upload it.

Comment: Please read the link. We aren't asking for you to upload your project. We are looking for a minimal example that shows your problem.

Comment: I should have said I have a minimal reproducible project. It requires several files and project settings. I guess I can insert them, but it seems less useful.

Comment: That is exactly the expectation. That you add the necessary code directly into your question. The reason is so that someone in the future has the context for understanding the question and any answers in this one place.

Comment: Are you saying that just having `@Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase` in the `@main`, without using it anywhere, is enough to pop the view with the button?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I just faced the same issue. Did you find any workarounds? @ToddHoff

Comment: Sorry, no, but I haven’t tested it in 17